# Как сверстать Флекс элементы в две колоны?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сверстать flex элементы в 2 колонны при разрешение 250px & 991px. Вот как это должно выглядеть на мобильном устройстве:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой неудачный код:

```css
.item {
 
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
   margin-right: 10px;
  
}


.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 
}



@media (min-width: 250px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .items {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `columns: 2;` вместо `flex-direction: column;`

Comment: @MaxWatson спасибо большое за совет. попробовал его сейчас. к сожалению не получилось :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вот решение:
https://jsfiddle.net/ctka8z1y/

## HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col1">
    <p>1 левая</p>
    <p>2 левая</p>
    <p>3 левая</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col2">
    <p>1 правая</p>
    <p>2 правая</p>
    <p>3 правая</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.col1, .col2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

@media (min-width: 250px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col1, .col2 {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

p {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогло